# form validation using ajax/jquery in Joomla

Tags: ajax, jquery, joomla, joomla1.5

I want to create custom form validation in joomla using ajax or jQuery. **on-blur** when user input a invalid thing it should validated and show the error and all error messages should read from xml. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the class name to get control event in joomla instend of controlID with Jquery.

need any further help it then give me more info about your post.

Comment: I have used JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');. But I want to modify it to show error messages on-blur and all the error messages should read from a XML. any other code will be appreciated.